# two svg element has weird behavior in IE10

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a situation with 2 svg elements. I have simplified and removed everything I can and still be able to reproduce the effect in IE10. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xuyzf/) is the jsfiddle.
Running the code in Chrome it looks right, but in IE10 the shape is completely black. However, If I remove the first svg it works in IE10.

I think it has to do with

```
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="fadeout" x2="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" class="dark"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" class="light"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="fadein" x2="0" y2="1">
        <stop offset="0%" class="light"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" class="dark"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

but I don't understand why and how! Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have multiple elements with the same id, this is invalid. All ids in a file must be unique.

Comment: ok, thnx. I tried to change the id into a class [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xuyzf/4/) but that doesn't seem to work. Why isn't that possible ?

Comment: A fill is an [IRI](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#IRIReference) it must be an ID not just any URL.

Comment: is there anyway to define the <defs> block once and let the <svg> use it. Or is the only solution to change the IDs ?

Comment: I don't understand. Why create/have the first block at all?

Comment: I add the same svg twice, thats all (its a template)

Comment: Have a flag to indicate that it's already added and don't add it again perhaps?

Comment: in reality both svg elements draw something :)